# How to get GPS Longitude and Latitude for android

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

Sorry about the long code post, didn't want to miss anything (i am a very beginner).
I looked at other answers and that's how i put this code together (I think i am doing it right) because i ran it

- On android 2.2 emulator and it works it grabs the correct weather based on Long and Lat.
- On my friend's phone it said weather is unavailable.
- On my uncle's phone (nexus 5) it crashes and just stops working.

Reason i used 2.2 emulator (using geo fix long lat through telnet-ing into the emulator port) because i don't know why on later emulators it always says weather is unavailable I am guessing later emulators doesn't support GPS testing.

I think it has to do with the getCurrentWeather() call below in this Weather class.
Please let me know what i am doing wrong or point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance!

I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

in AndroidManifest.xml

I want to state that it works like a charm on android 2.2 emulator.  And I get null location on later emulators.  And on actual phone (it's null location on my friend's phone when other apps are able to access his GPS location).  And on my uncle's phone (nexus 5) it just crashes (and since it's on the phone i don't know how to get the log from that since i don't know how to hook up to my computer).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Weather {
    public final static String CLEAR_SKY = "clear sky";
    public final static String FEW_CLOUDS = "few clouds";
    public final static String SCATTERED_CLOUDS = "scattered clouds";
    public final static String BROKEN_CLOUDS = "broken clouds";
    public final static String SHOWER_RAIN = "shower rain";
    public final static String RAIN = "rain";
    public final static String THUNDERSTORM = "thunderstorm";
    public final static String SNOW = "snow";
    public final static String MIST = "mist";
    public final static String WIND = "wind";
    public final static String ANY_WEATHER = "any weather";
    public final static String UNAVAILABLE = "unavailable";

    private static Double longitude;
    private static Double latitude;
    public static final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {


        }


    };
    public static String getCurrentWeather(Context ctx) {
        final JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        String return_weather = "";
        String URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";

        try {

            // Building Parameters ( you can pass as many parameters as you
            // want)
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
            Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (location == null){
                return (Weather.UNAVAILABLE);
            }
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", latitude.toString()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", longitude.toString()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("APPID",
                    "sampleappkey"));

            // Getting JSON Object
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "GET", params);
            //Log.e("Banana", json.toString());

            // get icon
            JSONArray weather = json.getJSONArray("weather");
            JSONObject weather1 = (JSONObject) weather.get(0);
            String icon = weather1.getString("icon");
            //Log.e("Icon", icon);

            //Log.e("Icon2", icon.substring(0, 2));

            int iconNum = Integer.parseInt(icon.substring(0, 2));
            switch (iconNum) {
            case 1:
                return_weather = Weather.CLEAR_SKY;
                break;
            case 2:
                return_weather = Weather.FEW_CLOUDS;
                break;
            case 3:
                return_weather = Weather.SCATTERED_CLOUDS;
                break;
            case 4:
                return_weather = Weather.BROKEN_CLOUDS;
                break;
            case 9:
                return_weather = Weather.SHOWER_RAIN;
                break;

            case 10:
                return_weather = Weather.RAIN;
                break;

            case 11:
                return_weather = Weather.THUNDERSTORM;
                break;
            case 13:
                return_weather = Weather.SNOW;
                break;
            case 50:
                return_weather = Weather.MIST;
                break;
            default:
                return_weather = Weather.ANY_WEATHER;
                break;
            }

            // get wind speed
            JSONObject wind = (JSONObject) json.getJSONObject("wind");
            Double speed = wind.getDouble("speed");
            //Log.e("Wind speed", speed.toString());
            //add condition to say wind when it's above certain speed and it's clear or cloudy
            if ((iconNum <= 4)&&(speed >= 30)){
                return_weather = Weather.WIND;
            }
            return (return_weather);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return (Weather.UNAVAILABLE);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return (Weather.UNAVAILABLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it crashes on your uncle's Nexus 5, you should be able to get a logcat/stacktrace from it. Also which 'later emulators' does it work on.

Comment: I solved this issue by using .getBestProvider() method.  It was related to when the GPS_PROVIDER isn't available.